# How to get list of all validators of Angular FormControl?

Tags: angular, form-control, angular-validator

I have a component with custom Form Control. And in this component I need to get list of validators from parent component. I use Reactive forms everywhere, so I don't need to inject NG_VALIDATORS, I don't need custom validators, I need exactly parent component validators.

Some example:

~parent.component.ts~

```
export class ParentComponent {

  public loginForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    password: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(6),
    ]),
  });
}
```

~parent.component.html~

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
    <child-component type="email" formControlName="email"></child-component>
    <child-component type="password" formControlName="password"></child-component>
</form>
```

~child.component.ts~

```
export class ChildComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit {

    valueControl = new FormControl('');  
  
    constructor( private injector: Injector ) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      const ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);

      // here I need something like this: const validators = ngControl.control?.validatorsList; 
      
      this.valueControl.setValidators(validators);
    }

  // some ControlValueAccessor interface
}
```

~child.component.html~

```
<mat-form-field>

  <input
    matInput
    [type]=type
    [formControl]="valueControl"
  />

</mat-form-field>
```

I see a couple of acceptable solutions:

1. Just pass to child component list of Validators with @Input like this:

~parent.component.ts~

```
export class ParentComponent {

  emailValidators = [Validators.required, Validators.email];

  public loginForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    email: new FormControl('', emailValidators),
    password: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(6),
    ]),
  });
}
```

~parent.component.html~

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
    <child-component [validators]=emailValidators type="email" formControlName="email"></child-component>
</form>
```

~child.component.ts~

```
export class ChildComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    
    @Input() validators;

    valueControl = new FormControl('');  
  
    constructor( private injector: Injector ) {

        this.valueControl.setValidators(this.validators);
    }

  // some ControlValueAccessor interface
}
```

2. Or receive form control errors on the fly and set validators based on them but this is an unjustified burden

~child.component.ts~

```
export class ChildComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit {

    valueControl = new FormControl('');  
  
    constructor( private injector: Injector ) { }

    ngControl.control?.statusChanges.subscribe(() => {

      // use ngControl.control?.errors

    });

  // some ControlValueAccessor interface
}
```

In connection with all the above I have a question:
Are there best practices to solve this issue? And also why Angular AbstractControl doesn't provide such a functional, but only has private variables like _rawValidators?

A huge thanks for any information or thoughts.

Comment: Does [this](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#validator) help you?